# How can I get values of inputs that have the same class using JQuery each?

Tags: jquery, html, class, backbone.js, selector

This should be easy, but I can't seem to get it right.

```
var totalHours = 0;
this.$(".timesheet-daily-input").each( function () {
    var inputValue = $(this).text();
    var hours = parseInt(inputValue);
    totalHours += (hours == null) ? 0 : hours;
});
```

I've tried `$(this).val()` and `$(this).html()` as well, but can't get the values out of the input fields.

Edit: Apologies, I knew I was forgetting to mention something. The "this." at the start of the each loop is because I am using backbone's models and collections. The first "this." refers to the specific model in question. It loops through the proper number of times, I just can't get the value.

Comment: What is the role of that _this_?

Comment: `this.$(".timesheet-daily-input").` is that a mistake ?

Comment: Remove the "this" before the $. Maybe it works if this is the window but it's not clean. And use val() to get the value.

Comment: what is your question? what isn't working?

Comment: It loops through the proper amount of times, but doesn't get any values. If I put `alert(inputValue)` after the `var inputValue` line, the alert box contains nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find an exact solution, but changed my approach by selecting the parent div, and looping through it's child elements.

```
var totalHours = 0;
this.$("#timesheet-daily-entry-fields-container").children().each(function () {
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    var hours = parseInt(inputValue);
    totalHours += isNaN(hours) ? 0 : hours;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `this.` before `$(".timesheet-daily-input")` and use `$(this).val()` to get the value of the inputs.

Comment: The "this." at the start refers to the specific model I'm using. I didn't mention that I'm using backbone's models and collections. If I don't include the "this." at the start, it loops through all my inputs instead of the specific model's inputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputValue = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without more code but change

```
var inputValue = $(this).text();
var hours = parseInt(inputValue);
totalHours += (hours == null) ? 0 : hours;
```

to

```
var inputValue = $(this).val(); // use val
var hours = parseInt(inputValue, 10); // use 10 as radix
totalHours += isNaN(hours) ? 0 : hours; // compare to NaN instead of null
```

Note that [`parseInt("09")` is `0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and that the result of parseInt cannot be `null`.