# How can I get values of inputs in a backbone model that have the same class using JQuery each?

Tags: jquery, html, class, backbone.js, selector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get values of inputs that have the same class using JQuery each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941215/how-can-i-get-values-of-inputs-that-have-the-same-class-using-jquery-each)

Using backbone's model and collection structure, I have this code:

```
var totalHours = 0;
this.$(".timesheet-daily-input").each( function () {
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    var hours = parseInt(inputValue);
    totalHours += (hours == null) ? 0 : hours;
});
```

The "this." before the loop indicates only inputs within the model in question. (If I don't include it, the loop goes through all my inputs, regardless of model, which is not desired).